# How to remove this error ? java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android, reflection, package, invoke

**I added All the needed permissions**

```
 PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Class<?> [] c = new Class[2];
    c[0] = String.class;
    c[1] = IPackageDataObserver.class;
    try {

    Object cleardata = packageManager.getClass().getMethod("clearApplicationUserData", c);
       Object[] o = new Object[2];
       o[0] = String.valueOf("my.app.withdata");
       o[1] = new ClearApplicationDataObserver();

    ((Method)cleardata).invoke(packageManager, o);
  }
    catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
 }

02-02 16:08:26.629: W/System.err(709): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-02 16:08:26.678: W/System.err(709):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 16:08:26.738: W/System.err(709):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 16:08:26.738: W/System.err(709):  at f.c.v.ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.run1(ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.java:105)
02-02 16:08:26.778: W/System.err(709):  at f.c.v.ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity$1.run(ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.java:52)
02-02 16:08:26.778: W/System.err(709):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-02 16:08:26.778: W/System.err(709): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10048 nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA.
02-02 16:08:26.778: W/System.err(709):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
02-02 16:08:26.778: W/System.err(709):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
02-02 16:08:26.808: W/System.err(709):  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.clearApplicationUserData(IPackageManager.java:2568)
02-02 16:08:26.808: W/System.err(709):  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.clearApplicationUserData(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1006)
02-02 16:08:26.808: W/System.err(709):  ... 5 more
```

Comment: You've asked the same question before.

Comment: yes i've asked but did not get the answer.

Comment: @johnsmith - If you want people to pay attention to your old Question, 1) update it as required, and 2) post a Bonus.  (You have enough rep points for that!)  Don't just repost the Question ... 'cos the repost will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

nvocationTargetException is due to unability of system to invoke an activity, and it is becuase there is another error on activity, please check the real issue is: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10048 nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA. and its because you need to set this permission in android manifest file.

Comment: I added the permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA not working

Comment: then clean and launch your app, again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this permission to your application's Manifest.:

```
android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA
```

Comment: I added the permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA not working

Comment: Well go back and check that you have added the permission **the right way**!!  Clearly the security manager *still says* that the application does not have the required permission ... no matter what you think you have done.